# Adding media_ids to Twitter API call causes authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a simple web page which can create a text-only tweet through the Twitter REST API at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json sucessfully. I am also able to upload a JPG image to Twitter with https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json and get back a numeric `media_id` successfully. **What I cannot do is put these two together to create an image tweet: it gets HTTP status code 401 if I add in the media_id!**

I am using ASP.NET (I have both VB and C# examples) but I expect the problem is not specific to this language. The only two bits of the tweet code I am changing are where the same 'querystring' is built up:

```
var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}&media_ids={7}";
var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, oauth_token, oauth_version, Uri.EscapeDataString(TweetText), TwitterMediaID);
```

and

```
var postBody = "status=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(TweetText) + "&media_ids=" + TwitterMediaID;
using (System.IO.Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
```

All this really does is append `&media_ids=1104003004334784512` to the end of the string. The rest of my code does not change.

The JSON I am returned is:
`{"errors":[{"code":32, "message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

If I remove `&media_ids=12345678901234567` then the code is successful (HTTP status code 200, and lots of useful JSON returned).

I don't believe I need any special permissions to create an image tweet, compared to a text-only tweet. I have read various blogs which mention people had intermittent HTTP 401 errors when using media_ids, which were nothing to do with authentication at all, but none of the solutions they offer applied to my sitation.

**The documentation suggests my media_id is good for 2 hours, so how can I be making a mess of the authentication aspect, when my text-only tweets are appearing on my Twitter profile OK?**

Comment: Are you relying on another library to handle making the OAuth request or did you implement that. The signature  requires the `baseFormat` to be sorted alphabetically: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html

Comment: @osowskit you are a beautiful and wonderful person. Thank you for taking away my frustration. I moved `media_ids` to the start of the string, and suddenly it all worked. I did read a lot of documentation, but sadly not that page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter requires that API requests use [OAuth 1.0a authentication](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request). One caveat is that the HMAC-SHA1 signature must be created in a very specific format.

In this case, it requires the `baseFormat` to be sorted alphabetically - see https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html

Comment: up Up UPVOTE!  That was it.  Parameters in the baseFormat string need to be alphabetized, so "media_ids" goes first before all the oauth tokens.  string baseFormat = "media_ids={7}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&status={6}";